# Xcode Swift - Is there an opposite to .contains?

Tags: swift, xcode, contains

Is there a way to determine if string **does not** contain something in an if statement? Basically the opposite of **.contains**  .

Example of contains:

```
if someItem.contains(x) {
code
}
```

Example of what I am looking for:

```
if someItem.doesNotContain(x) {
code
}
```

Where a slolution for **doesNotContain** is what I am looking for.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

*FYI, I am new to Swift and to programming, thank you for your comments.

Comment: so you can use else part for that

Comment: Boolean negations can be done using NOT, the `!` operator. There is also `satisfyAll`.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I'm still looking for something that satisfies the question of an exact opposite of .contains . Meaning I want to deliberately single out something just like you can with .contains, but the opposite.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Its as simple as NO is the opposite of YES. `if someItem.contains(x) == false` OR `if !someItem.contains(x)`.

Comment: @TheTiger , 

 True, but what I am looking for is a way to bypass executing an if statement, if it already is containing something specific.
 Say in my case, if I press the decimal key, it adds a decimal. But if I press it more than once, it crashes the app.
 Now I bet there are many ways of preventing this, but I am simply wondering if there is an exact opposite to .contain, regardless to any other workarounds.  Upon reading some of the other comments, it looks like Swift does not have it, unless someone know otherwise?
I also hope this helps anyone else looking for a similar  situation.

Comment: @CrazyOne I'm still not getting why you need `doesNotContain` function. There are only two cases either it contains or not. So `doesNotContain` is same as `contains == false`. If you want to check if the string contains decimal or not then `if !str.contains(".")` will work. It depends on you that you want to write the code in `if` block or `else` block but this is correct.

Comment: @thetiger thank you, I am new to programming in general, and thought there was a simple oppsite solution to .contains, which meakes sense to me and my situation.  I will give your suggestion a try soon, and check back.  Pardon my ignorance, just starting out.

Comment: @CrazyOne Feel free to ask any query if you have any confusion. I have No problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here are the results:


First off, I removed “without using a true/false Boolean” from my question in order to avoid confusion and to better suit the answer/solution. 

 Is there a code that is opposite to .contains? Simple Answer: NO.

It turns out that contains(_:) is a Boolean in of itself. This I did not know since I am new to coding.

 The solution is actually quite simple as we can state this Boolean to be true or false, as suggested by @The Tiger.

```
if someItem.contains(x) == false
```

or

```
if someItem.contains(x)
```

Tested this, and works like a charm.  
Opens up a bunch of new oportunities for me, and I hope this helps out fellow coders in search of something like this.

Thank you all for your comments and helping me find the answer, Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

No Apple doesn't provide any function like `doesNotContain` or something similar.

But if you don't want to add `else` part then you can simply use:

```
if !someItem.contains("hello") {
    //This means your someItem doesn't contain "hello" string.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this way

```
if !someItem.contains(x) {
code
}
```